# Estimate the minimum of a summation from two sets of numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, discrete-optimization

Given two sets of numbers:
$$A = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}, B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n\}$$
and assume the sumation $\sum_i a_i = \sum_i b_i =0$ vanish. How to estimate the minimum $s$ in the following?

$$s = \min_{\sigma} |S(\sigma)| \equiv \min_{\sigma} \Big| \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_{\sigma(i)} \Big|,$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

Furthermore, how to characterize the probability distribution of $S(\sigma)$?

PS: The question becomes simple if we remove the absolute value in $S$, as we have the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: Estimate in what sense? As some kind of simple function of $A$ and $B$? As an efficient algorithm?

Comment: I have no idea about this. Maybe the variance? Or the maximum gap? I wonder if there's any literature on this? I don't know what keywords to search.

Comment: Subset sum has a reduction to this, so you can't expect an efficient solution